# Recurse through a tree to find a node and return the path leading to node

Tags: java, recursion, path, tree

I am trying to write a recursive method that finds a particular node in a binary tree, and returns the path from root to the node. Once the needle is found, I should be recursing up the tree and concatenating a node.id to my returned string for every node I pass.

```
private String findPath( Node n, String needle )
{
    if ( n == null )
       return null;
    if ( n.key == needle )
       //not sure what to do here
}
```

That is what I have so far. I know I can use:

```
findPath( cur.left, name );
findPath( cur.right, name );
```

to recurse down through the tree, but I am not sure how to recurse back up and create my path.

Comment: you don't "recurse back up". recursion is always a "down" thing. you RETURN back up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
if(name.compareTo(needle)==0)
    return name;
If(name.compareTo(needle)>0)
    return name+this.right.findpath(needle);
If(name.compareTo(needle)<0)
     return name+this.left.findpath(needle);
```